# Need help converting SQL Server query to SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have this query running against my SQL Server:

```
SELECT SongUID, ArtistAlias, TitleAlias, Quality 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ArtistAlias, TitleAlias 
                          ORDER BY Quality Desc) AS rn, * 
     FROM KaraokeLibrary) dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

But I cannot get it to run under SQL Server CE 4  (`ROW_NUMBER()` not supported and `OVER...PARTITION` not supported).

I've been able to get "close" in SQL Server CE with this query:

```
SELECT SongUID, ArtistAlias, TitleAlias, Quality 
FROM KaraokeLibrary A
WHERE Quality >= 0 AND Quality IN (SELECT MAX(Quality) 
                                 FROM KaraokeLibrary B 
                                 WHERE B.ArtistAlias = A.ArtistAlias 
                                   AND B.TitleAlias = A.TitleAlias)
ORDER BY ArtistAlias, TitleAlias
```

But that still lists duplicate artist/titles - cannot have this.

Any SQL Server CE gurus have some query magic for me on this one?

UPDATE: To further explain – the final results I am after is when given data that looks like this:

```
SongUID  ArtistAlias  TitleAlias  Quality
    10,    'Artist1',    'Title1',    3
    11,    'Artist1',    'Title1',    2
    12,    'Artist1',    'Title1',    1
    13,    'Artist2',    'Title1',    3
    14,    'Artist2',    'Title1',    2
    15,    'Artist2',    'Title1',    1
    16,    'Artist2',    'Title2',    2
    18,    'Artist2',    'Title2',    1
    19,    'Artist2',    'Title2',    3
    20,    'Artist2',    'Title2',    3
    21,    'Artist2',    'Title2',    1
```

I would like to have this returned:

```
10, 'Artist1', 'Title1', 3
13, 'Artist2', 'Title1', 3
20, 'Artist2', 'Title2', 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just using a subquery:

```
select k1.SongUID,
  k1.ArtistAlias, 
  k1.TitleAlias,
  k1.quality
from KaraokeLibrary k1
inner join 
(
  select max(quality) maxQuality,
    ArtistAlias, TitleAlias
  from KaraokeLibrary
  where  Quality >= 0
  group by ArtistAlias, TitleAlias
) k2
  on k1.ArtistAlias = k2.ArtistAlias
  and k1.TitleAlias = k2.TitleAlias
  and k1.quality = k2.maxQuality
where  k1.Quality >= 0
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/452082/4)

If you have multiple versions of the `songuid`, then you can use an aggregate:

```
select max(k1.SongUID),
  k1.ArtistAlias, 
  k1.TitleAlias,
  k1.quality
from KaraokeLibrary k1
inner join 
(
  select max(quality) maxQuality,
    ArtistAlias, TitleAlias
  from KaraokeLibrary
  where  Quality >= 0
  group by ArtistAlias, TitleAlias
) k2
  on k1.ArtistAlias = k2.ArtistAlias
  and k1.TitleAlias = k2.TitleAlias
  and k1.quality = k2.maxQuality
where  k1.Quality >= 0
group by k1.ArtistAlias, 
  k1.TitleAlias,
  k1.quality
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d465/2)

Comment: BF - that is very similar to what I came up with. And produces the same result set.  Which is very close - but not quite

In looking at my data it appears that if I have many copies of the same ArtistAlias and TitleAlias the query works fine.  I see only one result row for That ArtistAlias and TitleAlias with the Max Quality.  

However on data items where there are 3 or less rows of the same ArtistAlias and TitleAlias - I get ALL of them in the result rows in the output.  
I don't understand why the difference between having 2 or 3 rows of same Artist/Title and 4 (or more) rows.

Comment: @WilliamMadonnaJr. I am not sure I fully understand but if you have matching `artistalias` and `titlealias` then can you use an aggregate function on the `songuid` -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d465/2

Comment: first I'd like to say "WHAT A FREAKIN COOL ASS WEB SITE!!!"   Never seen this sqlfiddle.com before.

Second - you are right - I am getting different results there than I do my live data.  I'm gonna play with that web site until either I get it to look like my live data and figure out why - or get my live data to behave like your query (and figure out why it didn't)

I will post my results here for future readers of this post.  Stand by....

Comment: @WilliamMadonnaJr. yes sql fiddle is great for these types of questions. :)

Comment: @bluefoot - ok got it!  The query you posted here did't match the query over on sqlfiddle.com: 
   
select max(k1.SongUID),
  k1.ArtistAlias, 
  k1.TitleAlias,
  k1.quality
from KaraokeLibrary k1
inner join 
(
  select max(quality) maxQuality,
    ArtistAlias, TitleAlias
  from KaraokeLibrary
  where  Quality >= 0
  group by ArtistAlias, TitleAlias
) k2
  on k1.ArtistAlias = k2.ArtistAlias
  and k1.TitleAlias = k2.TitleAlias
  and k1.quality = k2.maxQuality
where  k1.Quality >= 0
group by k1.ArtistAlias, 
  k1.TitleAlias,
  k1.quality
ORDER BY ArtistAlias, TitleAlias

Comment: @WilliamMadonnaJr. I did not update my answer with the version from the sql fiddle until I knew it was working.  I have now updated my answer here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also write the query like this:

```
SELECT  SongUID, ArtistAlias, TitleAlias, Quality
From KaraokeLibrary kl
where quality > 0 and
      songuid = (select top ( 1 ) songuid
                 from Karokelibrary kl2
                 WHERE kl.ArtistAlias=kl2.ArtistAlias AND kl.TitleAlias=kl2.TitleAlias
                 order by quality desc
                )
```

(Note:  you don't need the spaces in "top ( 1 )".  It is the only way I could upload the solution.)

Older versions of SQL CE may not support `top`.

Comment: Gordo - that just gives me the first Artist/Title.  See my edit to my original post with sample data and desired output.  

With this query I get SongUID 10 and 13 fine enough - but not 20